# git checkout does not work when backgrounded

Tags: git, ssh, nohup

I am trying to get a ssh trigger that will do something with git repository. When I run the code on background, it works. Adding a `nohup` does not have effect. The relevant bit just says:

```
git checkout master
Already on 'master'
```

But when I finally background it, it stops working with:

```
git checkout master
fatal: unable to write new index file
```

(output is directed to a log file; that is done on foreground as well; the log file includes the command being executed).

I've printed the `id` and `umask` at the beginning of the script and they look the same. And in both cases it's executed by ssh trigger, the only difference is `&` after the command.

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GIT_DIR=/somewhere
nohup git-using-script.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
sleep 1
```

Without the sleep 1, the nohup does not start (the redirections happen before the nohup starts, ssh manages to exit before the nohup creates a new session and the command is terminated anyway). But without the `&` everything else works, with it the script runs, but git produces the error.

Comment: how are you backgrounding the process? Is it possible that the current working directory or user changes?

Comment: @bundacia: I am backgrounding it with `&` combined with `nohup`. And sleep, because without it the ssh disconnects before the nohup changes session and takes the process out anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference I could think of is that with the ssh already down there is no tty and git is trying to access it for some reason or another. So I worked it around by using `script`(1). The resulting invocation is somewhat insane, but it works:

```
nohup script -qec "/path/to/git/script.sh args" /dev/null \
    </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I suspect the attempt to get the controlling terminal (it was not connected to any stream even before) has something to do with output paging, though I don't see why `git checkout` would need that. Nor why it should fail the operation.

Comment: What if you explicitly tell the SSH client to not allocate a PTY (the `-T` command-line option)?